# redux-immutable and initialstate

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am confused as to what is happening with state in my react app that is using redux, redux-immutable and immutablejs.

My reducers looks like this:

```
export const initialState = Map({
  isFetching: false,
  forecast: List()
});

export function forecast(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case ActionTypes.FORECAST.REQUEST:
    return state.merge({
      isFetching: true
    });
  case ActionTypes.FORECAST.SUCCESS:
    return state.merge({
      isFetching: false,
      forecast: action.response
    });
  case ActionTypes.FORECAST.FAILURE:
    return state.merge({
      // isFetching: false
    });
  }

  return state;
};

export function errorMessage(state = null, action) {
  const { type, error } = action;

  if (type === ActionTypes.RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE) {
    return null;
  } else if (error) {
    return {errorMessage: action.error};
  }

  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
  forecast,
  errorMessage,
  routing: routerReducer
});
```

Here is how I am creating the store:

```
  import reducers from '../reducers';
  const initialState = Map();

  const store = createStore(reducers,
                            initialState,
                            compose(
                              applyMiddleware(
                                thunkMiddleware,
                                logger
                              )
                            ));
```

And in a connected component, I am passing this function to connect:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    forecast: state.get('forecast'),
    isFetching: state.get('isFetching')
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchForecast
})(Forecast);
```

But if I look at the state that is getting passed into `mapStateToProps`

It appears to be a map made up of the 3 reducers I combined with the following code;

```
export default combineReducers({
  forecast,
  errorMessage,
  routing: routerReducer
});
```

I could change my code in `mapStateToProps` to this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state = state.get('forecast')) {
  return {
    forecast: state.get('forecast').get('forecast'),
    isFetching: state.get('forecast').get('isFetching')
  };
}
```

But this feels wrong.  Why is my state made up of 3 reducers and not the initial state I specified here:

```
export const initialState = Map({
  isFetching: false,
  forecast: List()
});

export function forecast(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case ActionTypes.FORECAST.REQUEST:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux's "combineReducers" method takes multiple slice's of state and combines them into one state.  It is working correctly here.

Your `initialState` is being used within each individual reducer and is setting the initial state of those *slices* of the overall state.  It is not the initial state of the entire combined reducer.

The code you have will create an initial state of:

```
{
    forecast: {
        isFetching: false,
        forecast: List()
    },
    errorMessage: null,
    routing: //not shown in code provided
}
```

If, instead, you want forecast to begin with an initial state of "List()" rather than  the object, you should change the initial state you pass to the forecast reducer, here;

```
export function forecast(state = List(), action) {
```

And then create a separate reducer for "isFetching" if you want it to be a peer of forecast.